# how to execute another bot command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so i want to make a discord bot who has a few moderation capabilities and I want my bot to execute MEE6's `!warn` command but it never works. It`s always just writes the command but I can never get to execute it.

My script:

```
if ("something") in content:
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}**you cant do that!**")
        x = 1
        await message.channel.send(f"!warn {message.author.mention} you cant do that").format(message)
```

Comment: Maybe the MEE6 bot has a check on commands to make sure bots cannot use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work. Mee6, along with every well-written bot out there will respond to other bots. The only way to do this would be to use a self-bot, which are against discord's ToS